# How to avoid scrolling to top of page when using scrollTo

Tags: javascript, razor

I have the following code that stores the scroll position when the user leaves a page and scrolls back to that position when coming back to the page.  This is in a .net razor page html file.  However it always scrolls to the top of the page before scrolling to the correct position when loading the page.  Any way to stop this behavior as it is an unnecessary jerking movement that would distract the user?  I want it to scroll directly to the saved scroll position if possible.

```
//store scroll position before leave page
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', window.scrollY);
});

//scroll to saved position
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    var scrollPosition = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition') || '0', 10);
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
});
```

Comment: Perhaps move the code inside the domcontent loaded to just before the `</body>` instead?

Comment: maybe this is not possible since it needs to load the stuff before scrolling to the correct place otherwise there is no room to scroll if there is nothing?

Comment: I will try that my razor page currently doesn't have the html tags by default need to add them in.

Comment: `when the user leaves a page and scrolls back to that position when coming back to the page.` razor page is cshtml file so that the content is rendered in the server first including the event listener code. after the page is loaded in the browser, then the scoll code can be executed. If there's a method could help, I trust it should also take place in the server side.